# Using Google fonts for email signature

Tags: email, fonts, outlook, signature

I am using outlook as the email client. Due to some font problems, I have decided to use google fonts in the signature, so my expectation is whenever I send an email, and the font link is available in the signature, the receiver email client will automatically download the font from Google Server and display them. 
In the signature options, I have selected that the signature displayed should be of the type HTML, but I don't know how to specify that the font should be from google fonts. 
Can I somehow import google fonts in @Font-face? I am posting some code of my signtuare, kindly have a look. Thank you.

Signature :

```
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:1;
    mso-generic-font-family:roman;
    mso-font-format:other;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:0 0 0 0 0 0;}

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailAutoSig'></span><a
href="http://www.internet-legion.de/"><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailAutoSig'><span
lang=EN-US style='font-size:8.0pt;mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-hansi-font-family:
Calibri;color:blue;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-no-proof:yes'>www.internet-legion.de</span></span><span
style='mso-bookmark:_MailAutoSig'></span></a><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailAutoSig'><span
lang=EN-US style='font-size:8.0pt;mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-hansi-font-family:
Calibri;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-no-proof:yes'><o:p></o:p></span></span></p>

<p class=Mso
```

Comment: Web fonts are meant to be used in web. Not in Outlook, isn't it?

Comment: The reason I am doing it is all the time the font settings are getting messed up. I thought best way to maintain consistency is to download fonts and use it on client side.

Comment: Use common fonts like Arial, or use images.

Comment: @Raptor : Unfortunately I cannot, can you tell me how to use google fonts.

Comment: No, you can't. Javascript scripts are usually stripped away when emails are received.

Comment: I don't want to use javascript, just simple font import with something like @import and the url.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423338/css-font-stack-substitution-issues-in-outlook-when-using-google-webfonts)

Comment: This dialog helped me.

Comment: I've never found a way to make this possible @We are Borg I can do this with a fallback on a HTML email but not on an email signature so far.

Answer (score 3):

Google Fonts arent web-safe fonts. You should never use non web-safe fonts in an email signature. Web-safe fonts are basically fonts which are installed on most devices worldwide. If you use a font which isn't web-safe and don't specify a fallback font, you run the risk of the whole text not being visible on the device that you're sending the email to.

Have a [look here](https://blog.gimm.io/what-are-the-best-fonts-for-email-signatures/) for more about web-safe fonts.

Comment: It will probably be visible but it will use a default font on Outlook, so Times New Roman, no matter what fallback you have picked, it will just ignore the lot.