# Email design - font weight on google fonts

Tags: html, css, html-email, webfonts

I'm coding an email template, and I want to use Google Fonts.
This code below, links to google fonts:

```
<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Open+Sans:400,300,600|Work+Sans:400,300);

[style*="Open Sans"] {font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif !important}
</style>
```

And, below some piece of code:

```
<td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif, 'Open Sans';font-weight:300;">Some text</td>
```

And this code works well in Outlook and others, but for example Outlook don't respect

```
font-weight:300
```

My question is, why ? Is this possible to have google custom font with font weight option ?

Comment: Take a look here - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ - Outlook's `CSS` support since 2007 has been shocking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS font stack substitution issues in Outlook when using Google Webfonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423338/css-font-stack-substitution-issues-in-outlook-when-using-google-webfonts)

Comment: Thanks, but this table show, that Outlook uses font-weight....

Comment: Hmm that's true. Note that `Arial` and `Open-Sans` are already included in Outlook, so it could be that it isn't importing, so the `font-weight` you want isn't available.

Comment: This is not duplicate. I wrote, that font works as expected - im using Open Sans, and open sans is rendered, the problem is only with font-weight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Outlook doesn't support web fonts**](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). Even though you're referencing Open Sans, the font you're actually seeing in Outlook is Arial, which does not have a 300 weight.

Web font support in email clients [isn't great](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/), so fallback system fonts are important. You can reference web fonts using the [`<link href=''>` tag](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2012/12/using-web-fonts-in-email/) instead of `@import` to increase your coverage a little.

Comment: So, no way to use Open sans in outlook 2016 for example ?

Comment: No, not in Outlook 2007/2010/2013/2016. They all use MS Word as a rendering engine.

Comment: I'm confused as i see a lot of hacks for outlook, and authors said, that this works, for example:
http://blog.postup.com/outlook-fix-for-using-webfonts-in-your-email

Comment: That article does not explain webfonts will work in Outlook, it explain that if webfonts are not done correctly (to display in other clients), Outlook will break and display times new roman.

Comment: I tested this out a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467381/can-outlook-2010-use-a-web-font-in-an-html-email/21485767#21485767