# Outlook 2007 is ignoring the CSS font styles in emails

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Like much of the corporate world, the majority of our clients unfortunately use Outlook as their email provider. In the email I'm working now, ***Outlook is ignoring the CSS font styles and replacing it with Times New Roman***. I've researched this issue and have found ample solutions (outlook class attribute, inline CSS styling in all `<td>` tags, and placing style tag closer to text) that have worked for most of the text in the email, but have left a few main pieces of text in Times New Roman.

I have screenshots from Mailchimp to show what it SHOULD look like, and then from litmus to show how Outlook 2007 is rendering it.

Disclaimer: For this email we used a template bought from envato's themeforrest, and I'm told some of the code is pretty wonky to begin with, but I don't know enough to improve it.

- **Code:**

  - [Link to Code in Gist](https://gist.github.com/bbc03ba2c81bc313fe33.git)
  - (I've removed sections not mentioned here)
- Screenshot :

  - 1 - Main Picture Section
  - 2 - Testimonial Section
  - 3 - CTA/ "Interested" Section

[image]

Comment: In case you're wondering why I removed much of the text of your question:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216604/133242

Comment: That said, there's nothing in your gist, and a _link_ to code is not sufficient. The code must be included in the question itself. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: As far as the gist being empty - its just that the link to the gist is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on web fonts for email, its unreliable. A lot of email clients will only support system fonts, so your best bet would be to choose a fallback font when your web font fails.

You need to verify if the version of Outlook you are targeting even supports web fonts.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/webfonts/

As for your layout issues, you need to have a solid understanding HTML emails in order to fix those issues.

EDIT:

Check this out: [Outlook 2007 / 2013 not rendering CSS font-family declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204812/outlook-2007-2013-not-rendering-css-font-family-declarations)

Answer (score 0):

Unable to see your code  with gist link
but, this is just a hunch, maybe you can try to give the font part of your code it own style tag.